# Exact value of sin (θ/2) if cos θ = 3/5

Tags: trigonometry

Exact value of $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ if $cos θ = \frac{3}{5}$ and $360° < θ < 450°$:

Okay, so I put this into the half argument property and got:

$$\sin\frac{\theta}{2} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}}$$

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: A friendly reminder that it helps to make your question more easily readable by visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a brief explanation on how to type mathematics on this site in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We very well know that $$\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A \implies sinA=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos2A}{2}}$$ As required, set $A=\frac{\theta}{2}$ & $\cos\theta=\frac{3}{5}$ thus we get $$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}} \implies \sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{3}{5}}{2}}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $$ Now, as per given constraints of $\theta$ $$360^o<\theta<450^o \implies 180^o<\frac{\theta}{2}<225^o$$ Now, we are to select the value with the correct sign. It's is obvious from the above constraints that the angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$ lies in the III-quadrant where 'sine' has negative value,  thus the required value is negative. Hence, the correct value $$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Answer (score 3):

You know the bisection formula:
$$
\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|=
\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}
$$
In your case
$$
\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|=
\sqrt{\frac{1-3/5}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}
$$
Since
$$
180^\circ<\frac{\theta}{2}<225^\circ
$$
you should know whether $\sin(\theta/2)$ is positive or negative.

Comment: The value of $\cos\theta$ is given $\frac{3}{5}$ it's not $\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot It changed after I wrote the answer! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin \theta =\frac 35$(Draw a right triangle).

Now use that $\sin 2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\implies \sin 2\theta=\frac{24}{25}\implies ?$
Make sure to get the correct range of the arcsin function in order to get the correct $\theta$.

Comment: Surely the sine and cosine aren't the same...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: The question was edited. Originally it stated $\cos\theta=4/5$

Answer (score 0):

That formula has always given me a headache, so I turn it around.
$$\cos 2\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg) = 1-2\sin^2\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\frac{3}{5} = 1-2\sin^2\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\sin^2\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)=\frac{1}{5}\implies \sin\bigg(\frac{\theta}{2}\bigg)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Why is $\frac{\theta}{2}$ a third quadrant angle?